# Conflitos entre double tap e click. (jQuery e Hammer.js)

Tags: jquery

Eu estou tentando algo diferente, gostaria de implementar algo semelhante a um recurso do Instagram: dois tapas para dar like.

Para tentar fazer isso, estou usando as últimas versões do jQuery e do Hammer.js. Não sou um programador avançado nesta área, entretanto eu cheguei até a seguinte lógica para identificar qual o evento que o usuário deseja executar:

```js
var postDoubleTapped;
postDoubleTapped = false;

Hammer($('.post').get(0)).on('doubletap', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  postDoubleTapped = true;

  console.log('Double tap!');
  return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '.post a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(postDoubleTapped);

  setTimeout((function(_this) {
    return function() {
      if (!postDoubleTapped) {
        location.href = $(_this).attr('href');
      }
      postDoubleTapped = false;
    };
  })(this), 500);
  return false;
});
```

Como vocês podem visualizar no exemplo (http://codepen.io/caio/pen/vqEjc), não funcionou! O `console` retorna:

[image: Console]

Existe outro problema, eu não consigo reproduzir o `target="_blank"` na tag `a`.

Este é o melhor método para fazer isso? Eu estou no caminho certo? Como eu posso arrumar isso?

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que o `setTimeout` é chamado duas vezes: uma no primeiro clique/tapa e outra no segundo. O que está sendo retornado no console é natural: 1) o primeiro é detectado, imprime `false` e cria um `setTimeout`; 2) o `Hammer` trata do `doubletap`, imprimindo `Double tap!`; 3) o segundo é detectado, imprime `true` e cria um novo `setTimeout`.

O primeiro `setTimeout` executa, atribuindo `postDoubleTapped` de novo pra `false`. Quando o segundo `setTimeout` executa, essa variável já tem valor `false`, de modo que ele faz o redirecionamento.

Para solucionar o problema, vamos por partes:

1. Para uma solução rápida, salve o valor de retorno do `setTimeout` numa variável e - antes de criar outro - destrua-o usando `clearTimeout`:

   ```
   var ultimoTimeout = null;

   ...

   $(document).on('click', '.post a', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log(postDoubleTapped);

       if ( ultimoTimeout !== null )
           clearTimeout(ultimoTimeout);
       ultimoTimeout = setTimeout((function(_this) {
           ...
   ```
2. Para uma solução "correta", o interessante seria impedir o evento tratado pelo `Hammer` de propagar. Primeiro, notei que você está usando o `event` global, em vez de pegar o parâmetro da função, mas não creio que isso tenha feito diferença na prática:

   ```
   Hammer($('.post').get(0)).on('doubletap', function() {

   // Não deveria ser:
   //Hammer($('.post').get(0)).on('doubletap', function(event) {
   ```

   Além disso, você chama o `preventDefault`, mas não o `stopPropagation` (esse sim *deveria* impedir o evento de propagar - chegando a ser tratado pelo jQuery). Digo "deveria" porque - por alguma razão que desconheço - usá-lo não parece ter feito diferença... Notei que o `target` do evento tratado pelo `Hammer` é a imagem, não o hiperlink, mas isso não deveria importar - já que a imagem está *dentro* do link. Não compreendo o que está havendo, de modo que um *workaround* seria usar a solução proposta no item 1.
3. Por fim, não importa se seu link possui `target="_blank"` ou não, já que você está fazendo - via JavaScript - uma redireção da janela corrente pro novo endereço (mas isso você próprio já tinha percebido, né?). A solução é usar `window.open` em vez de mexer no `location.href`:

   ```
   if (!postDoubleTapped) {
       window.open($(_this).attr('href'), $(_this).attr('target') || "_self");
   }
   ```

   Isso vai fazer com que o *browser* tente abrir a URL na janela especificada pelo atributo `target` do seu link (no caso, `_blank`) ou - se esse atributo não existir - na própria janela (`_self`). No meu teste, o Chrome bloqueou o redirecionamento (como se fosse um popup) e - de acordo com [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4907843/520779) - não há muito o que se possa fazer a respeito...

   [Pelo que eu li](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13158856/520779), o problema está no `setTimeout` - se a abertura da janela fosse consequência direta do clique do usuário (i.e. ocorresse enquanto o próprio evento de clique estivesse sendo tratado) então creio que o browser abriria normalmente. Mas como ele ocorre num momento arbitrário (quando o `setTimeout` executa) o bloqueador de popup acha que o site tentou abrir uma janela por conta dele, e não deixa. Quanto a isso, receio que não tenho nada a sugerir por enquanto...

Comment: Informações adicionais: [essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17176642/520779) sugere usar `window.stop` no `ondblclick` para parar a troca de páginas, mas creio que ela só funcione (se é que funciona) na página atual. [Essa outra](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2181464/520779) propõe uma alternativa, entretanto como o comportamento é semelhante a de um "pop under" (i.e. mais usado "pro mal" que "pro bem") muitos *browsers* não a permitem (no Chrome, por exemplo, não funcionou). Finalmente, aqui está [um argumento](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4989867/520779) desencorajando esse uso.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda, estou considerando todas as suas observações e tentando reconstruir meu código (deixar de utilizar o Hammer.js pode até vir a ser uma opção). No item 2 você disse sobre o `target` do `Hammer`. Isso não acontece pois são seletores diferentes nos eventos?

Comment: @CaioTarifa Eu não entendo o suficiente de eventos no DOM pra saber *por que* isso acontece (pois o [`$('.post').get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) no seletor do Hammer também se refere ao hiperlink), mas sei que isso não deveria importar: eventos no `img` propagam pro `a`, que propagam pro `.post` até chegar no `document` (onde ele é tratado pelo `on` do jQuery). Isso tudo ocorre "por baixo dos panos" - independente da framework/biblioteca - por isso estranhei bastante quando o `stopPropagation` não funcionou...